# Use custom bitrate / better: bitrate per channel in Gnome Sound Converter (esp. for opus)

Tags: gnome, soundconverter, ogg-opus

as the title says: Is there any way to to this? Is there any linux alternativ you can recommend (GUI). Currently I am using TAudioConverter via Wine, but A) it's buggy with m4a that have embedded the cover art in a weird way and B) it's opus codec hasn't been updated in a while.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WinFF, a gui front end for ffmpeg

```
sudo apt-get install winff
```

Open WinFF and then close it again. Open the preferences file located at

```
~/.winff/presets.xml
```

add the following section then save the file and reopen WinFF

```
  <opus>
    <label>Opus</label>
    <params>-acodec libopus -b:a 256k -vbr on -compression_level 10</params>
    <extension>opus</extension>
    <category>Audio</category>
  </opus>
```

That is set to 256k vbr and ffmpeg seems to convert to 48000Hz by default

If you choose the Convert to: dropdown as 'Audio' in WinFF, the Preset: section will then have an Opus setting to select

You can make as many of the above presets as you like for different bitrates etc, just the outer tags need to be renamed  and the label changed to whatever you want.

The full list of Opus options can be found using

```
man ffmpeg
```

To inspect the output install the following

```
sudo apt-get install opus-tools
```

then use

```
opusinfo foo.opus
```

to look at what you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my free app [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html), it is a ffmpeg GUI.
You can also procees files in bulk mode.

[image]